# Image URI error in loading from firebase, no host specified in URI

Tags: firebase, flutter

I created a user account and added user's name and profile pic on sign up.

The on the profile page I am fetcing the result, I am getting email and name but image is not being displayed.

I get the following error.

```
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:

Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI

file:///data/user/0/com.example.project/cache/image_picker6223730245122398943.jpg
```

How can I reslove this error. I tried adding http in the start of url but it did not work.

Comment: The `file:///` points to a file on the user's local device, so that won't exist on other users' devices. But it's hard to say what you'll need to change beyond that. "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error message, the faulty URL is:

```
file:///data/user/0/com.example.project/cache/image_picker6223730245122398943.jpg
```

As Frank explained why it won't work, you also need to know what is causing this problem. You are storing the path for the image as it is on the device of the user who took the image. For example `user/documents/images/image.jpg`.
If you send this link to anybody online, it won't open. You need to take this file, and upload to a storage provider, for example firebase storage, get the download link for that file, and this is the link you want to store in your Firestore database.